# PySimpleGUI Change Table row color based on value (substring) condition

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I have been using PySimpleGUI and am trying to apply the following function:  I am trying to work out how to change individual row colors (and/or change those row text colours) of an "updating" table based on a substring present in a column. For example with this sample code from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pysimplegui/pysimplegui_table_element.htm, if I wanted the row color to change to green if substring "Ra" is present in column 1, is it possible?  I think I would need to insert this code:

```
window['-TABLE-'].Update(row_colors=[[ROW TO CHANGE,'green']])
```

but do not know how to have a substring search on each row of a particular column as an event and to then apply that code to the appropriate row.  Thanks

```
import PySimpleGUI as psg
psg.set_options(font=("Arial Bold", 14))
toprow = ['S.No.', 'Name', 'Age', 'Marks']
rows = [[1, 'Rajeev', 23, 78],
        [2, 'Rajani', 21, 66],
        [3, 'Rahul', 22, 60],
        [4, 'Robin', 20, 75]]
tbl1 = psg.Table(values=rows, headings=toprow,
   auto_size_columns=True,
   display_row_numbers=False,
   justification='center', key='-TABLE-',
   selected_row_colors='red on yellow',
   enable_events=True,
   expand_x=True,
   expand_y=True,
 enable_click_events=True)
layout = [[tbl1]]
window = psg.Window("Table Demo", layout, size=(715, 200), resizable=True)
while True:
   event, values = window.read()
   print("event:", event, "values:", values)
   if event == psg.WIN_CLOSED:
      break
   if '+CLICKED+' in event:
      psg.popup("You clicked row:{} Column: {}".format(event[2][0], event[2][1]))
window.close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the value of column 1 for each row if it contain the substring "Ra", then call method `update` of `Table` element to update the colors.

> row_colors
>
> list of tuples of (row, background color) OR (row, foreground color, background color). Changes the colors of listed rows to the color(s) provided (note the optional foreground color)

Reduced code

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

headings = ['S.No.', 'Name', 'Age', 'Marks']
rows = [
    [1, 'Rajeev', 23, 78],
    [2, 'Rajani', 21, 66],
    [3, 'Rahul', 22, 60],
    [4, 'Robin', 20, 75],
]

table = sg.Table(
    values=rows,
    headings=headings,
    justification='center',
    selected_row_colors='red on yellow',
)
layout = [[table], [sg.Push(), sg.Button("Check")]]
window = sg.Window("Table Demo", layout)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == "Check":
        row_colors = [(i, "white", "blue") for i, row in enumerate(rows) if "Ra" in row[1]]
        table.update(row_colors=row_colors)

window.close()
```

[image]